# Events in heiress classes of java swing

Tags: java, swing, class, events

I am creating an application, with java swing.

With two main classes:

i suppress some code...

```
public class OnOffButton extends javax.swing.JPanel{
    private JButton btnOn= new JButton("On");
    private JButton btnOff= new JButton("Off");

    private void btnOnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        this.setOn(true);
     // I want to generate an event to be handle in another class

    }                                     

    private void btnOffActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        this.setOn(false);
        // I want to generate an event to be handle in another class
    }                                      
    public void setOn(boolean boOn) {
        btnOff.setEnabled(boOn);
        btnOn.setEnabled(!boOn);
    }

}
```

and:

```
public class MainScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final OnOffButton system;
    private final OnOffButton flush;

    //Something like
    private void systemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     
    //Something like
    private void flushActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     
}
```

When one of the buttons of the OnOffButton class generates an actionPerformed I need to make a handle on MainScreen.

thanks for help...

PS: It would be something like "connect" in C ++ ...

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for some Swing basics.

Comment: You need to implement a observer pattern so that the `OnOffButton` class can generate events that the `MainScreen` register to and be notified of state changes

Comment: Get it, i will try that..